# Free in-app product, non-consumable, on Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing

For any successful consumable purchase, I want to remove the ads. Which at it's turn it must be a non-consumable so it can be restored.

ItunesConnect has a Free Tier, but Google Play Console doesn't. Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to just have a flag saved in the shared preferences that is turned true when the user makes a purchase? Then, before you load/display any ads, you check if that flag is true or not, and if it is, you don't display the ads.

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for replying. I wouldn't worry for any purchases at all in this case. The idea is that the user could restore his transactions after reinstalling the app.

Answer (score 2):

The In-app Billing Version 3 service only supports managed in-app products or subscriptions. That means that all consumable and non consumable items are managed items.

If you uninstall the app, the purchase information still exists on the Google server linked with the user account and you can request for it when you reinstall the app.

Quoting the [docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#managed)

> When a user purchases a managed in-app item, Google Play stores the
>   purchase information for each item on a per-user basis. This enables
>   you to later query Google Play at any time to restore the state of the
>   items a specific user has purchased. This information is persistent on
>   the Google Play servers even if the user uninstalls the application or
>   if they change devices.

You should not consume the purchase since removing an ad permanently after purchase means it was a non consumable in app product.

[Non consumable products](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consumetypes)

> Typically, you would not implement consumption for in-app products
>   that can only be purchased once in your application and provide a
>   permanent benefit. Once purchased, these items will be permanently
>   associated to the user's Google account. An example of a
>   non-consumable in-app product is a premium upgrade or a level pack.

So when you reinstall the app, query for purchases for the user and if a valid non consumable item purchase is found, hide your ads.

Comment: Hi random, thanks for your reply. In my app I have 3 Consumable items and for purchasing any of them I want to purchase for free (or do whatever with it without requesting money for the user) the ads Non-Consumable.
Could I query for items that have been consumed? Or can i buy not consumed items multiple times?

Comment: Hi, @random I appreciate your answer. Could you help me by giving kind informatio?  I have an app, the only income source is ads. I want to implement in-app billing to remove ads for 30 days, 60 days like this as a consumable product. Can I do that? Will it be go Against policy?

Comment: Hello there, please correct the sentence "You should not consume the purchase since removing an ad permanently after purchase means it was a non consumable in app product." since it's wrong. If you do not consume a product after 3 days the user will be refunded the money spent. So this is not a valid flow.